# Call remote procedure in a RESTful way

Tags: rest, web-services

I want to make a webservice which provides endpoints through which a user can generate and manipulate configuration files saved in a database.
The endpoint

```
https://api.example.com/generate-new
```

should execute a procedure which generates a standard configuration file for the user. 
A RESTful webservice should return the complete config file as an answer (state transfer).
Since the config files also contain sensitive information like api keys, this is not possible here.

I would like to only return a success message. A HTTP-200 would be enough.
But is this approach still RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself: What is the Resource (the 'R' in REST) here? It sounds like the Resource is something like a **User Configuration Generation Task**. The URL should reflect this:

```
https://api.example.com/user-configuration-generation-tasks
```

Let's say a HTTP POST request to this collection resource creates a new task, maybe using information passed in the request body. The server executes this task and generates the new user configuration.

Now you have three options for what to return:

- [`201 CREATED`](https://httpstatuses.com/201): This would require to include the `Location` of the user configuration in the response. Since you don't want to make the configuration accessible, this is no option.
- [`200 OK`](https://httpstatuses.com/200): This would indicate general success of the operation. But since you don't plan to return any response, I don't suggest this. Instead us
- [`204 NO CONTENT`](https://httpstatuses.com/204): The server has successfully fulfilled the request and there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.

All this is perfectly RESTful.